# Why does Boto 3 occasionally timeout connecting to SNS

Tags: python, networking, boto3, amazon-sns

We're trying to diagnose an occasional problem that comes up with an application calling SNS, resulting in application timeouts.

We created a test case which pushes 1,000,000 messages into SNS. Most of the messages go through in under 2 seconds, but occasionally (somewhere between 1 in 30,000 and 1 in 100,000) the message takes just over 60 seconds to complete - this is too slow for my use case.

We found that Boto 3 has retry logic which, by default, will wait 60 seconds, then retry the request - this is the behavior I'm seeing for that small percentage of requests, with the first retry attempt succeeding.

This is the test:

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my-profile', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
sns =  session.client("sns")
topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:my-sns-topic"
for x in range(0, 1000000): 
    response = sns.publish(Message="Test", TopicArn=topic_arn)
```

Trying to find out why that first request fails, we ran a WireShark trace to get more information, and found some interesting results.

The majority of requests to SNS are initiated with a `Client Hello` using **TLSv1.2**, and are quickly answered with an `ACK` and then a `Server Hello`.

The requests which time-out/fail initiate with the `Client Hello` using **TLSv1**. This is answered with an `ACK`, but **no** `Server Hello` - after 60 seconds we see `FIN, ACK` from the client.

[image]

We've confirmed that when we only see TLSv1 being used for ~0.001% of `Client Hello` requests, and that whenever TLSv1 is used, the request times out.

Why is Boto 3 occasionally using TLSv1 to initiate the connection? Is this something within Boto 3 (boto3 1.11.15, botocore 1.14.15), Python (3.6.8), Operating System (Amazon Linux 4.14.154-99.181), or elsewhere? What can we do to further diagnose and correct the behavior?

Unfortunately adjusting the thresholds on the retry policy is not a valid solution for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/security.html#enforcing-tls-1-2) Boto3 documentation could help you resolve this issue by using a different Python build with a static reference to TLSv1.2

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/security.html#enforcing-tls-1-2